# Calling R as a web service with parameters and load a JSON?

Tags: json, r, web-services, shiny

I am pretty new with `R`. What I am trying to do is to be able to load a URL from another application (Java) which will run an `R` script and output a `JSON` so my application can work with it.

I understand there are some frameworks like `shiny` which act as web servers for R,  but I can't find documentation on those frameworks on how to pass parameters via the URL so R can use them.

Ideally I will need to call a URL like:

```
http://127.0.0.1/R/param1/param2
```

And that URL will call an R script which will use `param1` and `param2` to perform some functions and return a `JSON` which I will then read from my app.

Comment: I don't know of a rest framework for R. You might want to look at Rserve and the associated java client

Comment: Have a look at https://www.opencpu.org/

Comment: Google "R CGI script". A few solutions. This one https://rforge.net/FastRWeb/ was maintained recently, from a trusted source in the R community.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate all solutions proposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have not done so yet please checkout [[DeployR]](http://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/). You can also post questions to the **DeployR Google Group** for help.

For full disclose I am one of the authors of **DeployR**

**Overview**

DeployR is an integration technology for deploying R analytics inside web, desktop,mobile,and dashboard applications as well as backend systems. DeployR turns your R scripts into analytics web services, so R code can be easily executed by applications running on a secure server.

Using analytics web services, DeployR also solves key integration problems faced by those adopting R-based analytics alongside existing IT infrastructure. These services make it easy for application developers to collaborate with data scientists to integrate R analytics into their applications without  any R programming knowledge.

DeployR is available in two editions: **DeployR Open** and **DeployR Enterprise**. **DeployR** Open is a free, open source solution that is ideal for prototyping, building, and deploying non-critical business applications. 
**DeployR Enterprise** scales for business-critical applications and offers support for production-grade workloads, as well as seamless integration with popular enterprise security solutions such as single sign-on (SSO), Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP), Active Directory, or Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM).

> I am pretty new with R

Prefect. DeployR is intended for both the Data Scientist as well as the application developer who might not know R.

> What I am trying to do is to be able to load a URL from another application 
>   (Java) which will run an R script and output a JSON so my application can work with it.

DeployR does this quit well. To aid in the communication  between your application
and the DeployR server (that will be executing your R) there are the [DeployR Client libraries](http://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/docanddown/#clientlib).

Depending on your needs, DeployR has out-of-the-box 'client library' support in:

- [Java-client-library](https://github.com/deployr/java-client-library): `https://github.com/deployr/java-client-library`
- [.NET-client-library](https://github.com/deployr/dotnet-client-library):  `https://github.com/deployr/dotnet-client-library`
- [JavaScript and Node.js-library](https://github.com/deployr/js-client-library): `https://github.com/deployr/js-client-library`

DeployR also supports the [RBroker Framework](http://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/dev/rbroker/)

should your use-case or runtime anticipate a high-volume workload or the need for periodic, scheduled or batch processing.

> I understand there are some frameworks like shiny which act as web servers for 
>   R, but I can't find documentation on those frameworks on how to pass parameters 
>   via the URL so R can use them

DeployR acts as your analytics engine through its APIS. Basically think of it as 
turning your R scripts into secure analytic web services to be consumed like any 
other web service.

**Pass parameters**

Passing parameters to an R Script in DeployR is easy, however you have to  understand that you are passing parameters to an R Script from a language that is not R. As such, there is some 'Data Encoding' that needs to be done. For example, turn your Java String into an `R character` or your Java boolean to an `R logical`...
The DeployR Client library or RBroker makes this easy.

It sounds like you are using Java, so first review the Java tutorial **java-example-client-basics** `https://github.com/deployr/java-example-rbroker-basics` to give you some context then checkout the many Java examples under **java-example-client-data-io** `https://github.com/deployr/java-example-client-data-io`.
The example source is fully available so that should give you everything you need
in order to understand how to do basic I/O from your application to the DeployR server for your R analytics.

> Ideally I will need to call a URL like:
>   `http://127.0.0.1/R/param1/param2`

I suggest using the **DeployR Client libraries** for your communication as described above, it does just that.

As always post questions to the *DeployR Google Group* `https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/deployr` for help.

Comment: DeployR Open has been suspended by microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You have some options to do that, IMHO [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/) is a nice one.

It's the simplest open source way to implement a web server to provide R computation as a REST service.

The creator of OpenCPU is the same author of [jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package, and you can easily get and pass json parameters with OpenCPU, as you can see [here](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-json).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to implement REST API web service in R is a [plumber](http://plumber.trestletech.com/) package (formerly *rapier*). It uses function decoration approach within special comments:

```
# myfile.R

#* @get /mean
normalMean <- function(samples=10){
    data <- rnorm(samples)
    mean(data)
}

# service.R

library(plumber)
r <- plumb("myfile.R")  # Where 'myfile.R' is the location of the file shown above
r$run(port=8000)
```

Then invoke it:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/mean"
```