# Creating a webservice running R scripts

Tags: json, r, web-services

Good morning everyone,

I am starting to develop with R and I need to create a web service to execute some R scripts and have a JSON in return.

For example :

When I go to this link `http://myserver:1234/script/param1=xxx`

I want to execute an R script with the parameter `xxx`and have in return a JSON for example with `Hello World`

I found some tools as **OpenCPU** or **DeployR** but I couldn't manage to install them as DeployR needs an Windows Server and OpenCPU isn't well documented.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Please don't tell me it's [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141204/calling-r-as-a-web-service-with-parameters-and-load-a-json) because I couldn't find my answer there, **DeployR** isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use our 5Analytics Platform. It allows you to deploy R or Python. Just upload your code and it automatically generates webservices out of it.

Create a simple R script (can be complex too)

```
    # create simple R script
    > echo "test_curl <- function() { 2 }" > test.R
```

Upload the script via webdav (or with a web gui)

```
 

    # upload file to server via webdav
    > curl -u usr:pswd --digest -T test.R 'http://localhost:5050/up/dav/'
```

Query the webservice with http

```
    > curl "http://localhost:5050/if/json/R/v1/test_curl?_token=test_token"
    {
        "data": [1.0]
    }
```

Here some more documentation:
http://doc.5analytics.com/

Here a link to the homepage:
https://www.5analytics.com/en/technology/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative might be using AWS Lambda.

In [this](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) excellent blogpost it is explained how to create an R microservice.

How does it work:

You host an AWS Lambda function (=microservice) running Python that internally uses `rpy2` to run your R-code.

Answer (score 1):

Note that DeployR is obsolete. The replacement for it is [R Server Operationalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/about), and it works with [both Linux and Windows.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/configuration-initial)

> The operationalization feature for Microsoft R Server is supported on:
>
> - Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016
> - Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04,
> - CentOS/RHEL 7.x