# Make a web application written in R a webservice

Tags: r, web-services, web-applications, webserver, web-development-server

I have a web application in R. The application is written using Shiny R. It involves predictive models. I want to make it a web service which can be linked to another website. How can it be done?

Comment: Check out [plumber](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2018/07/23/rest-apis-and-plumber/)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141204/calling-r-as-a-web-service-with-parameters-and-load-a-json